# How do you pay Lightning Recovery’s action cost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

The Iron Heart maneuver *lightning recovery* has an initiating time of 1 immediate action, and is used in response to an attack you missed.

However, this is a little confusing: the [definition of immediate actions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#immediateActions) says that, when used during your turn, it uses that turn’s swift action:

> Using an immediate action on your turn is the same as using a swift action, and counts as your swift action for that turn.

A swift action generally could not be used between an attack roll and a damage roll, as *lightning recovery* must be, and more importantly, using this turn’s swift action would mean you would have to leave the swift action open—that is, not use a boost—if you wanted to leave the option of *lightning recovery* available.

So my question is, should *lightning recovery* be used as a true immediate action, even when you use it during your turn, or must it be treated as a swift action—and if so, how does that even work?

Answer (score 4):

For "how does it even work" (specifically for uses on your own turn): RAW is clear.  It's an immediate action.  When made on your turn, it acts as a swift action - requiring and consuming your swift action opportunity for that turn.  Swift actions can be taken at any time that free actions can be taken.  There are two ways to take the order of operations from that point, and both of them have the same result.  In the first, you miss your attack.  Your attack completes.  You have an opportunity to use free actions (as it is on your turn, and you are not currently in an attack).  You use Lightning Recovery, rewind a bit, and reroll the attack roll.  In the second, we assume that the rules text implies an immediate reaction to the failed roll before the attack officially fails.  In that case, that's how it works here as well, and Specific Beats General papers over any issue that there might be with when you get to use swift actions.

As far as whether or not it "should" work that way... there does not appear to be any strong reason that it should not.  The fact that it consumes a swift action on your turn and therefore cannot be comboed with a boost is a limitation on the power of the move, but at least some limits of that sort are RAI in the general case, or we wouldn't have swift actions to begin with.  The maneuver is still useful and effective (a reroll with bonus to hit that you can pull out after you see what you rolled the first time?  Yeah, there's a use for that).  It's not a wasted slot even without the nova potential of stacking with both a boost and an attack.  It is distinct from and superior to the equivalent pre-buff boost maneuver because of flexibility in action - you don't have to decide whether or not to expend the maneuver (and consume your swift action) until after you make the attack.  There are meaningful swift actions that are not boosts.  Additionally, it does permit use in out-of-turn actions, in a way that a swift action boost might be harder-pressed to do.

This isn't a particularly *strong* negative argument.  Adjusting the maneuver so that it consumed the swift action for the next turn rather than the current turn would be an upgrade (especially for the sort of player who would ask for it specifically) but it shouldn't be a particularly extreme or gamebreaking one unless the character so adjusted was already somewhat overpowered compared to the rest of the table.  At that point, it's DM's fiat as to whether or not they want to houserule in your favor.  For me, though, I wouldn't.  The maneuver works fine RAW, and the tactical decisions are arguably more interesting when you can't just play the "stack it all on one attack" game.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer okay.  I've rewritten it a bit to make clearer how I was addressing the two questions asked by the OP (how does it work, and should it be changed).  The argument of "there's nothing wrong with it as is, therefore RAW wins the should game by default" is made clearer, and I believe somewhat better supported.  Could you take another look and tell me what you think?

Comment: I still disagree, but your answer is much better now.  Downvote removed.

Comment: This answer is a bit wordy, but comes to the correct conclusion. When used on your turn RAW, an immediate action counts as a swift. If you use your swift before you attack, that equates to using your immediate during your turn. That being said, I agree that perhaps that it might not have been RAI..... but that falls under DM fiat/homebrew territory.

Answer (score 0):

Converting *lightning recovery* into a swift action doesn’t seem in keeping with the spirit of the maneuver to me, since the maneuver is very much an “interrupt” type ability that really hinges on the timing rules of using an immediate action *outside* your turn, even when you initiate it during your turn. In effect, *lightning recovery* only makes sense if you can use it to interrupt because you have to interrupt yourself in order to use it.

Furthermore, the entire purpose of the maneuver is to increase the likelihood that a singular attack—which is presumably a high-value attack loaded with bonus effects from a boost and/or strike—lands on the target. It being an immediate action is important to its function and role. If the intent was for the maneuver to require preparation to use, it would just be a boost that said something like “for your next attack that misses,” instead of being initiated after missing.

So for both of these reasons, I consider it crucial to this maneuver’s proper functioning that it use your next turn’s swift action, not this turn’s.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61182/discussion-on-answer-by-kryan-how-do-you-pay-lightning-recoverys-action-cost).

Answer (score -2):

My reading of the Immediate Action rules do not cause the conflict you're seeing.  An immediate action is still an immediate action on your turn.

Plus, given that explicit beats general, and Lightning Recovery explicitly says it can be used in response to missing an attack, that beats the general rule anyway.

Thus, when using an immediate action on your turn, you consume the swift action for that turn.

Comment: “Using an immediate action on your turn is the same as using a swift action, and counts as your swift action for that turn.” You are objectively and explicitly incorrect. And while I fully agree that specific beats general, that still leads to questions of *how* specific beats general. Finally, you don’t address the fundamental question here: does using *lightning recovery* on your turn require reserving that turn’s swift action to do so?

Comment: What if you use your swift action for something, then attack, and miss. Surely you could use an immediate action for Lightning Recovery? And it would use up next turn's swift?

Comment: @FrancisJohn It's definitely not "surely". This is what the whole question is about. Can you explain what's wrong with you being unable to do it under such circumstances?